# How to resolve ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when hosting a React server on Replit?

Tags: html, node.js, replit

My problem is that i am getting this problem

**linkline-2.maaz-gamergamer.repl.co** sent an invalid response.

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I am hosting a server on replit of react

I tried chagnging port and get request to something other than it